# Android App on Multiple Devices

Tags: android, events, mobile

I have been developing a concept for an Android application for doctors to use, and it involves the use of an Android mobile phone and a tablet in the operation theater. I will have a clickwheel sort of menu on the app running on the phone, and another instance of the app running on the tablet. When a user selects an option using the wheel, this event has to trigger the rendering of a view on the tablet. I'm quite new to Android development, so any help on how this could be implemented would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get the devices on the same network (of some sort). And device some sort of communications whereby the phone can send the selected choice over the network to the tablet, and the tablet can then react by updating its UI.

This communication could be achieved in many different ways: Bluetooth, or Wifi I think are the easiest two to implement. Which one fits your use case better would be something we wouldn't know without more information though.

Comment: Thanks @FoamyGuy for the quick reply. I will give it a shot with the bluetooth API. The project is about enabling doctors in the OR with android devices, which they can use to get patient information, radiation levels, doctor availability and other info. The doctor will have an android phone under their smock near the left breast pocket, and use gestures to control the clickwheel i talked about earlier. Depending on the option selected on the clickwheel, the appropriate view has to pop up on the tablet, which is placed a little away, in a place where it is clearly seen.

Comment: Any additional info or suggestions you might have would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to be accomplished you have to have some sort of messaging system between the devices. You'd likely make some server API call on menu selection on the phone. From there you can have the web service kick off a GCM message to the tablet OR have the tablet polling the server every x seconds checking for the change and responding appropriately.

As FoamyGuy stated, bluetooth might also be a viable option.